# Cannot find SameSiteCookieManager using directive in .NET Framework 4.7.2 project for Auth0

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, auth0

I am attempting to add Auth0 SSO to an existing .NET Framework 4.7.2 project with ASP.NET MVC, however, in the Startup.cs file the project is unable to find the reference for SameSiteCookieManager anywhere. I have installed and imported the packages Microsoft.Owin.Security.OpenIdConnect and Microsoft.Owin.Security.Cookies as the Auth0 Quick Start guide states. The reference can be found when I download and run the Auth0 sample project, it is just within the existing project that this issue arises.

My Startup.cs file looks like this, 99% of which is taken directly from Auth0's website. The two instances of SameSiteCookieManager both return the same error.

```
using System.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Owin;
using Microsoft.Owin.Security.Cookies;
using Microsoft.Owin.Security;
using Owin;
using Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb;
using Microsoft.Owin.Security.OpenIdConnect;
using Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens;
using Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.OpenIdConnect;
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

[assembly: OwinStartupAttribute(typeof(IPS.WebClient.Startup))]
namespace IPS.WebClient
{
    public partial class Startup
    {
        public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
        {            
            string auth0Domain = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["auth0:Domain"];
            string auth0ClientId = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["auth0:ClientId"];
            string auth0RedirectUri = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["auth0:RedirectUri"];
            string auth0PostLogoutRedirectUri = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["auth0:PostLogoutRedirectUri"];

            // Set Cookies as default authentication type
            app.SetDefaultSignInAsAuthenticationType(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);
            app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
            {
                AuthenticationType = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType,
                LoginPath = new PathString("/Account/Login"),

                // Configure SameSite as needed for your app. Lax works well for most scenarios here but
                // you may want to set SameSiteMode.None for HTTPS
                CookieSameSite = SameSiteMode.Lax,

                // More information on why the CookieManager needs to be set can be found here: 
                // https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetKatana/wiki/System.Web-response-cookie-integration-issues
                CookieManager = new SameSiteCookieManager(new SystemWebCookieManager())
            });

             // Configure Auth0 authentication
    app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions
    {
        AuthenticationType = "Auth0",

        Authority = $"https://{auth0Domain}",

        ClientId = auth0ClientId,

        RedirectUri = auth0RedirectUri,
        PostLogoutRedirectUri = auth0PostLogoutRedirectUri,

        TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
        {
            NameClaimType = "name"
        },

        // More information on why the CookieManager needs to be set can be found here: 
        // https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/samesite/owin-samesite
        CookieManager = new SameSiteCookieManager(new SystemWebCookieManager()),

        Notifications = new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationNotifications
        {
            RedirectToIdentityProvider = notification =>
            {
                if (notification.ProtocolMessage.RequestType == OpenIdConnectRequestType.Logout)
                {
                    var logoutUri = $"https://{auth0Domain}/v2/logout?client_id={auth0ClientId}";

                    var postLogoutUri = notification.ProtocolMessage.PostLogoutRedirectUri;
                    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(postLogoutUri))
                    {
                        if (postLogoutUri.StartsWith("/"))
                        {
                            // transform to absolute
                            var request = notification.Request;
                            postLogoutUri = request.Scheme + "://" + request.Host + request.PathBase + postLogoutUri;
                        }
                        logoutUri += $"&returnTo={ Uri.EscapeDataString(postLogoutUri)}";
                    }

                    notification.Response.Redirect(logoutUri);
                    notification.HandleResponse();
                }
                return Task.FromResult(0);
            }
        }
    });
            
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I'm in the process of adding OIDC with Auth0 as well to a MVC application in .NET Framework 4.8 and am having the same issue of not able to find the SameSiteCookieManager class anywhere. Did you ever get this resolved?